# How to maintain modal on top for submition without loading the page on click

Tags: php, form-submit, bootstrap-modal

I have created a modal with a form in it. I want it whene a user tries something ivnalid and clicks 
submit the page not to reload but stay there unti the user clicks close button or the submition is success.Any idea how will i achieve this?I have finished everything the whole form,php validations of input.I just have this issue now!Thanks :)

Comment: Are you willing to use Javascript for form validation ?

Comment: I think javascript is not as secure as using php for validation rules!Still any help at any way will be appreciated! Thanks!